# Post request with Angular to NodeJS, Express

Tags: node.js, angularjs, post, service, express

I'm creating first app with angluar and also with nodejs with express framework so i have couple of questions.

1. How to post data (json) to server - how to pass json to server in post request, now works but does get request try to call appName:/#/games/game_id/results?priority=0&priority=0&...
2. When i get json back how to redirect to other angular view in that way that his controller could see that returned json from server

controllers.js

```
$scope.generate = function() {
    Generator.gPriority({gameId: $routeParams.gameId, priority: $scope.priority}, function() {
        $location.path("/games"); //redirect when get json from server to other view/controller/partias and process json ...show json in table
    });
};
```

service.js

```
var appServices = angular.module('appServices', ['ngResource']);

appServices.factory('Generator', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('games/:gameId/results', {}, {
            gRandom: {method:'GET', params:{gameId:''}, isArray:true},
            gPriority: {method: 'POST', params:{gameId:'',priority: '@priority'}}
        });
    }
]);
```

server.js

```
app.post('/games/:id/results', generator.gWithPriority);
```

generator.js

```
exports.gWithPriority = function(req, res) {
    var priority = req.body;
    console.log('Game priority: ' + JSON.stringify(priority));
    res.json({
     "numbers": [
            [[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],[1,2]],
            [[3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,3]],
            [[4,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2]]
         ]
    });
};
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I can help with number 2. If you want to share data between controllers, use a service. For example:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('DataService', function(){
    var data = {};
    return {
        getData: function() { return data; },
        setData: function(newData) { data = newData; }
    };
});
```

Use the setter in the callback of `Generator.gPriority(...)` and use the getter in the controller of the new view. That way you can pass data from one controller to the service and then retrieve that data from other controllers.